# Get model's fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, introspection, metamodel

Given a Django model, I'm trying to list all of its fields.  I've seen some examples of doing this using the _meta model attribute, but doesn't the underscore in front of meta indicate that the _meta attribute is a private attribute and shouldn't be accessed directly?  ... Because, for example, the layout of _meta could change in the future and not be a stable API?

Is _meta an exception to this rule?  Is it stable and ready to use or is it considered bad practice to access it?  Or is there a function or some other way to introspect the fields of a model without using the _meta attribute?  Below is a list of some links showing how to do this using the _meta attribute

Any advice is much appreciated.

[[django object get/set field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763558/django-object-get-set-field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763558/django-object-get-set-field)

http://www.djangofoo.com/80/get-list-model-fields

[How to introspect django model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384436/how-to-introspect-django-model-fields)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Get list of model fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`_meta` is private, but it's relatively stable. There are efforts to formalise it, document it and remove the underscore, which might happen before 1.3 or 1.4. I imagine effort will be made to ensure things are backwards compatible, because lots of people have been using it anyway.

If you're particularly concerned about compatibility, write a function that takes a model and returns the fields. This means if something does change in the future, you only have to change one function.

```
def get_model_fields(model):
    return model._meta.fields
```

I believe this will return a list of `Field` objects. To get the value of each field from the instance, use `getattr(instance, field.name)`.

Update: Django contributors are working on an API to replace the _Meta object as part of a Google Summer of Code. See:
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/hD4roZq0wyk
- https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/new_meta_api

Comment: You should also be aware of he fact, that if you also need the many-to-many fields you need to access `model._meta.many_to_many`!

Comment: Thank you Will.  Good to know that other people are using _meta as well.  I like the idea of having a wrapper function.  Lazerscience, thank you also.  Good to know there is a nice method to get the many_to_many fields. Joe

Comment: def get_model_fields(self):
    return self._meta.fields                                                                       used this to easily return all model fields... Thanks very much...

Comment: `django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py` uses _meta to walk the tree of apps, models, and fields. Nice pattern to follow... and you can bet it's the "official way".

Comment: If you are using generic foreign keys you should also check `_meta.virtual_fields`

Comment: Field objects has a couple of methods/attributes, `attname`, `name`, `get_attname`. What's the difference between these?

Comment: [`_meta` is now a formal, supported API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/) (new in Django 1.8)

Comment: for Django 2.0.7 ，_meta.many_to_many doesn't work,should use _meta.local_many_to_many, and if you use a through model to represent m2m relationship, it won't appear

Answer (score 161):

I know this post is pretty old, but I just cared to tell anyone who is searching for the same thing that there is a public and official API to do this: `get_fields()` and `get_field()`

Usage:

```
fields = model._meta.get_fields()
my_field = model._meta.get_field('my_field')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Comment: This is actually right answer for newer version of django.

Comment: 1.10 `get_fields()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields

Comment: One question: if these are "public and official", why are they still under `_meta`?

Comment: @krubo It could be like `NamedTuple`'s `_replace`, where the underscore was added to prevent naming conflicts, not indicate that it's private. If you had a `meta` field, there would be a clash.

Answer (score 27):

`get_fields()` returns a `tuple` and each element is a `Model field` type, which can't be used directly as a string. So, `field.name` will return the field name

**`my_model_fields = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]`**
The above code will return a list conatining all fields name

**Example**

```
In [11]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [12]: User._meta.get_fields()
Out[12]: 
(<ManyToOneRel: admin.logentry>,
 <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: password>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: last_login>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_superuser>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: username>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: first_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: last_name>,
 <django.db.models.fields.EmailField: email>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_staff>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_active>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: date_joined>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: groups>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: user_permissions>)

In [13]: [field.name for field in User._meta.get_fields()]
Out[13]: 
['logentry',
 'id',
 'password',
 'last_login',
 'is_superuser',
 'username',
 'first_name',
 'last_name',
 'email',
 'is_staff',
 'is_active',
 'date_joined',
 'groups',
 'user_permissions']
```

Answer (score 17):

Now there is special method - [get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)

```
    >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    >>> User._meta.get_fields()
```

It accepts two parameters that can be used to control which fields are returned:

- **include_parents**

  True by default. Recursively includes fields defined on parent classes. If set to False, get_fields() will only search for fields declared directly on the current model. Fields from models that directly inherit from abstract models or proxy classes are considered to be local, not on the parent.
- **include_hidden**

  False by default. If set to True, get_fields() will include fields that are used to back other field’s functionality. This will also include any fields that have a related_name (such as ManyToManyField, or ForeignKey) that start with a “+”

Answer (score 11):

`fields = [f"{f.name}_id" if f.is_relation else f.name for f in model._meta.fields]`

Answer (score 10):

This is something that is done by Django itself when building a form from a model. It is using the _meta attribute, but as Bernhard noted, it uses both _meta.fields and _meta.many_to_many. Looking at django.forms.models.fields_for_model, this is how you could do it:

```
opts = model._meta
for f in sorted(opts.fields + opts.many_to_many):
    print '%s: %s' % (f.name, f)
```

Answer (score 6):

The model fields contained by _meta are listed in multiple locations as lists of the respective field objects.  It may be easier to work with them as a dictionary where the keys are the field names.

In my opinion, this is most irredundant and expressive way to collect and organize the model field objects:

```
def get_model_fields(model):
  fields = {}
  options = model._meta
  for field in sorted(options.concrete_fields + options.many_to_many + options.virtual_fields):
    fields[field.name] = field
  return fields
```

(See [This example usage](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2.3/django/forms/models.py#L154) in django.forms.models.fields_for_model.)

Comment: You might want to accompany your code with a brief description of what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one.

```
fields = Model._meta.fields
```

Comment: I imagine one might want to access the properties of a field. Also, as pointed out in previous answers, there are `many_to_many` and `virtual_fields`.

Comment: @Jocke right you are.  The need may arise to access another attribute.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this for your **admin** site, there is also the `ModelAdmin.get_fields` method ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields)), which returns a `list` of field name `strings`.

For example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # extending change_view, just as an example
    def change_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # get the model field names
        field_names = self.get_fields(request)
        # use the field names
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the django documentation 2.2 you can use:

To get all fields: `Model._meta.get_fields()`

To get an individual field: `Model._meta.get_field('field name')`

ex. `Session._meta.get_field('expire_date')`

Answer (score 1):

`instance._meta.get_fields()` returns a list of all the fields (i.e. columns) in a Django model.

This method is used to introspect the model's fields, their types, and their relationships with other models. The method returns a list of Field objects, which represent the individual fields in the model.

For example, suppose you have a Django model called `MyModel`. You can use `instance._meta.get_fields()` to get a list of all the fields in the model:

```py
from myapp.models import MyModel

my_instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
fields = my_instance._meta.get_fields()
```

The fields variable will now contain a list of all the fields in the `MyModel` model, including fields such as `id`, `name`, `created_at`, and any related fields (such as *foreign keys*). You can use this list to access and manipulate the individual fields in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is add functions to the model and when you want to override the date you can call the function.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def set_created_date(self, created_date):
        field = self._meta.get_field('created')
        field.auto_now_add = False
        self.created = created_date

    def set_modified_date(self, modified_date):
        field = self._meta.get_field('modified')
        field.auto_now = False
        self.modified = modified_date

my_model = MyModel(name='test')
my_model.set_modified_date(new_date)
my_model.set_created_date(new_date)
my_model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all fields in a concise and readable manner you can use "model_to_dict" to collect them into a dictionary:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

my_object = ModelName.objects.get(id=1) 
data_dict = model_to_dict(my_instance)
print(data_dict)
```