# Django model field by variable

Tags: python, django

Quick question. I'm trying yo access one of the fields of a model using a variable.

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
      the_field = models.CharField()
      the_field_two = models.CharField()
```

How would access the field dynamically? I tried:

```
model = ExampleModel.objects.get(pk=1)
fieldtoget = 'the_field'
test_var = model[fieldtoget]
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any ideas how I would do this?

**Update:** Thought I'd update my question. I'm trying to write a function (as part of larger function) that can not only get the value of the field but also update it from a variable fieldname. For example:

```
model[fieldtoget] = 'yo'
model.save()
```

In PHP you can use the {} wrapper - `$model{$fieldtoget}` - as an example, for dynamic variable names was hoping there was something similar in python :)

Cheers

Comment: You may also use the _meta attribute of the model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/django-get-a-models-fields

Comment: Using the word model for the instance variable of the ExampleModel is probably not a good idea. It is confusing. Perhaps using model_instance might be a better choice.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use pythons getattr function to do this. Pass the field name in as the attribute.

```
getattr(model, fieldtoget)
```

Since fieldtoget is a variable, this is dynamic.

You can use setattr to set it the same way.

Comment: amazing, this made my day!

Comment: I used setattr() and worked like a charm. Thanks for this post!

Comment: Hey how to do this if i want to get the nested field value, `field__ fieldtoget `