# django loop through model fields

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django get a model's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/django-get-a-models-fields)

I have next model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to loop through all items from People table.

In views.py

-When I try this one:

```
  for each in People().objects.all():
     name=each.name
```

I am getting that error:

```
Manager isn't accessible via People instances
```

-When I try this one:

```
  for each in People():
     name=each.name
```

I am getting this error:

```
'People' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix that and how to loop through all items from my People table ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`People.objects.all()`

it works on the class not an instance `People` not `People()`