# Django: how to get a model's keys

Tags: php, python, django

So I am trying to get into the world of Python and Django. Coming from PHP, many things are similar, but I have a hard time figuring out how to do the following.

In PHP I would do this:

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data');

foreach ($q->result_array() as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Now, my question is: how can I accomplish something similar in Django / Python?
I have this setup:

```
from index.models import Foo

def index(request):
    datalist = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
```

And then what?

Comment: what is the exact usecase ?

Comment: Not sure what the snippet is supposed to achieve in PHP—iterate over `id => object` pairs? or iterate over all the `key => value` pairs of all objects in the resultset?

Comment: Related, may be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django

Comment: btw, you're using an extremely high amount of whitespace in your code—it's really having a detrimental effect on its readability.

Comment: You can also do `datalist.__dict__`

Comment: @karthikr: no—`datalist.__dict__` gives the attrs of the LIST not each model instance; and even on model instances, it (often) gives more than what he wants.

Comment: did you see what OP is doing @ErikAllik - He is doing a `.get()`

Comment: @karthikr: ah, right; what a confusing variable name then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** The query in your PHP snippet does not even match the one in your Django snippet to start with. The PHP one does a `SELECT * FROM data` but the Python one does a `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = 1`, so I'm gonna go ahead and assume you intended `Foo.objects.all()` instead of `Foo.objects.get(id=1)`. If you didn't, then please fix your question, and also simply remove the looping part of the code snippets below. Also, you should find a better name for the variable `datalist` if it's going to contain just one item not a list as the name suggests, which was a source of confusion for me initially.

You haven't really described very clearly what your goal is, but here are a few options that might potentially match your needs:

```
for obj in datalist:
    print "%s => %s" % (obj.id, obj)
```

...or if you want to iterate over all key-value pairs of all objects:

```
for obj in datalist:
    print "OBJECT %s" % obj.id
    for field in Foo._meta.fields:
        print "  %s => %s" % (field.name, getattr(obj, field.name)
```

...or you can use the `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` helper to convert the objects to dictionaries:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

for obj in datalist:
    print "OBJECT %s" % obj.id
    for key, value in model_to_dict(obj_as_dict).items():
        print "  %s => %s" % (key, value)
```

Comment: So your first and second solution gives me a "object is not iterable".
The third option however works. Thank you so much!

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that `datalist` is not an iterable, even though its name suggests it is. I've added a comment at the beginning of the answer about this.

Comment: @DiederikvandenBurger: Read Erik's note to find out why you are getting the `Object is not iterable` error, he clearly explains that your django query will return _one_ result, not a list of results.

Comment: Hmm yeah, so it really is not a list indeed. Sorry for the confusing var name. If I only want to select one iteration, is the third option then the only possible option?

Comment: They all work with single items as well, just please **remove the loop** as mentioned in the **NOTE** and only use the loop body. It just program code not Chinese or anything.

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the confusion, though I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, I would suggest delving into Python and Django; for Python, see http://learnpythonthehardway.org; for Django, just http://djangoproject.com