# How to access a django models ordering from model instance (or class)

Tags: django, django-models

How do I programmatically get the `ordering` defined in `model.Meta` for a Django model `class` or an instance?

i.e. I want to get the `('foo', 'bar')` from:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.IntegerField()
    snake = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('foo', 'bar')
```

Neither `models.FooBar` nor `models.FooBar.Meta` have an attribute `ordering`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking *'private'* attribute `_meta`?

```
FooBar._meta.ordering
```

*(Also works on instances)*

*Similar:* [Get model's fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django)