# access model fields and attributes in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a simple scaffolding app in django, however I'm still not able to access a models fields and attributes(e.g. CharField, max_length=100, null=True, etc...). I know about the _meta class of models, but as far as I know it only retrieves basic info about the model not the fields. Is there a away to achieve this?

**Update:**
you can find the answer in this article:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/04/working-models/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get model's fields in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `get_field` method to get info for a particular field:

```
field = ModelName._meta.get_field('field_name')
```

Then you may check various attributes of field, like `field.blank`, `field.null`, `field.name` etc.

If on the other hand you want to get a list of all fields of a Model you should use `fields`:

```
fields = ModelName._meta.fields
```

For example to get the name of all your model fields you can do something like:

```
field_names = ', '.join(f.name for f in fields)
```

Hm... also I just noticed that your question is a duplicate of [Get model's fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django) !