# DRF how can i list choices from the Model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've got a model like this, and i want to show only List WEIGHT_CHOICES and the variables above such as (XSMALL, SMALL, MEDIUM etc). But when i have no idea what queryset should i make. Because when i put MyAnimal.objects.all() it shows me what i want, but it shows me it (if there are 100 instances in db) 100 times. Do you know how can i either get only one instance or just those choices as json file?

```
class MyAnimal(models.Model):

    XSMALL = 'XS'
    SMALL = 'S'
    MEDIUM = 'M'
    LARGE = 'L'
    XLARGE = 'XL'
    XXLARGE = 'XXL'

    WEIGHT_CHOICES=[
    (XSMALL, '>1kg'),
    (SMALL, '1-5kg'),
    (MEDIUM, '5-10kg'),
    (LARGE, '10-25kg'),
    (XLARGE, '25-50kg'),
    (XXLARGE, '<50kg'),]

    weight = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=WEIGHT_CHOICES, default=MEDIUM,)
```

```
class AnimalWeightSerializer(serializers):
    class Meta:
        model = MyAnimal
        fields = ('WEIGHT_CHOICES', 'XSMALL', 'SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE', 'XLARGE', 'XXLARGE',)
```

```
class AnimalWeightList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyAnimal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalWeightSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089083/access-model-fields-and-attributes-in-django) every models has a _meta class and you can access it to get your field choices

```
choices_models = MyAnimal._meta.get_field('weight').choices
```