# Django admin form fields attributes override

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Django 1.8. I've got model:

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    annotation = models.CharField(
        max_length=80, verbose_name='Additional info', blank=True, null=True,
        help_text='e.g. officce 412, 4 floor')
```

And I have task to expand form input field a bit for `Location` in `admin.py`. I made this by:

```py
class LocationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    annotation = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'size': 70}))
```

and here I lost my `verboose_name`, `blank=True` and `help_text` in admin form. I can fix this problem by:

```py
class LocationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    annotation = forms.CharField(
        required=not Location._meta.get_field('annotation').blank,
        label=Location._meta.get_field('annotation').verbose_name,
        help_text=Location._meta.get_field('annotation').help_text,
        widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'size': 70}))
```

but this variant looks so ugly... Are there any other alternatives here?

Comment: You could write a wrapper function that returns the fields that you would want. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django

Comment: agree- it is not nice, but I left it to be in my code, it is only a field in a form :)

Comment: @steph wrapper may be an option, thank you.

Comment: @Ohad i like clear and clean code thats why i asked this question :). And usual Django agree with me, but not in this time :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend to modify the css for this admin model instead of changing the form/fields, see [ModelAdmin asset definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions):

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("location_admin.css",)
        }
```

`myapp/static/location_admin.css`:

```
#id_annotation { width: 423px }
```