# Django: modify model’s field before save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model, *course*, with an `ImageField` and `FileField` so I’d like to create a folder each time the user create a course. I think I can do this before the model is saved so here is my question.

How can I access a model’s fields in a method?

**Models.py**

```
Class Course(models.Model):
 Thumbnail = model.ImageField(upload_to=“...”,...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargd):
        ... #How can I alter here the ImageField parameters?
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Access the model's fields or the instance of the model's fields?

Comment: Access to the model’s fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647936/6505847) on getting the model's fields.

To get field of an object instance then it should just be as

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     #### How can I alter here the ImageField parameters?
     self.Thumbnail = #do whatever you want here
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's not possible to alter field's params in a method. It must only be done in the field definitions because the model must be saved first

Comment: self.Thumnail is the instance, I'm trying to modify the model's field parameters so this doesn't work

Comment: That's exactly how i mentioned it. To get the model's field simply follow the link above it. :)

Comment: I have the model's field! Thank you! By the way, how can I modify now the parameters of the fields? I know that in widgets its something like:  `widgets.attrs.parameter(...')`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by params, you mean to alter this `(upload_to=“...”,...)`?

Comment: Yes, (upload_to=“...) and so on

Comment: I don't think that's possible to alter field's params in a method. It must only be done in the field definiitons

Answer (score 2):

Instance of the models field can be accessed using self like a normal instance variable.

For example in a model class below,

```
class DummyModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField()
    value = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.value # self.value is a model field.
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your case, you can access it using self.Thumbnail

Comment: Is there any way to modify the parameters of the model's field? Not the instance

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not possible to modify the model field's parameters before create it, as @azyCrw4282 said in his answer, it's possible to create a directory with the name of the model's instance and upload there the files parsing a function to **upload_to**

**models.py**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'user_course/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.name, filename) #instance.name will be the name of the course


class Course(models.Model):
    name       = model.CharField(...)
    thumbnail  = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, ...)
```