# Django - Replace model fields values before save

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Just to note:** I know about overwriting Model's [.save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152078/django-modify-model-s-field-before-save) method but it won't suit me as I explained it at the end of my question.

In one of my projects, I've got more than of 30 database Models and each one of these models accept multiple `CharField` to store store Persian characters; However there might be some case where users are using Arabic layouts for their keyboard where some chars are differ from Persian.

For example:

```
The name Ali in Arabic: علي
and in Persian: علی
```

Or even in numbers:

```
345 in Arabic: ٣٤٥
And in Persian: ۳۴۵
```

I need to selectively, choose a set of these fields and run a function on their value before saving them (On create or update) to map these characters so I won't end up with two different form of a single word in my database.

One way to do this is overwriting the `.save()` method on the database Model. Is there any other way to do this so I don't have to change all my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a completely [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/) however in your case it's really easier to just customize Django's `CharField`:

```py
class MyCharField(models.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None or value == "":
            return value  # Prevent None values being converted to "None"
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return self.func_to_call(value)
        return self.func_to_call(str(value))
```

Replace your models `CharField` with `MyCharField`.

And create the `.func_to_call()` so it does whatever you need to map the values:

```py
def func_to_call(self, value):
    # Do whatever you want to map the values
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use of Django's Signals.  With Signals you can call a function before or after save on one or more Models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.
>
> django.db.models.signals.pre_save & django.db.models.signals.post_save
>
> Sent before or after a model’s save() method is called.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#pre-save

> pre_save
>
> django.db.models.signals.pre_save
> This is sent at the beginning of a model’s save() method.
>
> Arguments sent with this signal:
>
> sender
> The model class.
>
> instance
> The actual instance being saved.
>
> raw
> A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.
> using
> The database alias being used.
>
> update_fields
> The set of fields to update as passed to Model.save(), or None if update_fields wasn’t passed to save().

You can connect signals to a Single, Multiple, or All models in your application.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(pre_save)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # logic here
```

In this case sender is the Model that is about to be saved,  instance will be the object being saved.

Comment: Thank you, but signals are really overkill for this problem as I have many models and fields. I ended up customizing `CharField`.