# Can't access "on_delete" argument of model field using _meta class (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Title. I'm trying to access the `on_delete` argument of the field "org" here:

```py
class OrgLocation(models.Model):
    org = models.OneToOneField(
        Org, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
    )
```

And I'm trying to access it with:

```py
OrgLocation._meta.get_field("org").on_delete
```

But when I run this, I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'on_delete'
```

Trying to access `primary_key` works just fine though (and same for `blank`). Not sure what's going on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to access on_delete value? It's not meant to be accessible. It's for letting django know, that how django should behave when you delete objects that have relationships.

Comment: I'd like to access it for unit testing purposes

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29423946/13861187

Comment: Did any of the answers below work?

Comment: Using remote_field to access the on_delete attribute did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `remote_field` attribute on the field to access the `on_delete` attribute, e.g.

`OrgLocation._meta.get_field("org").remote_field.on_delete`

Answer (score -1):

Try below.

`include_hidden`

[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)

[also look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40903764/13861187)

Comment: look at @A. J. Parr's answer.